# javascript callback function when an elements attributes change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am sure this is somewhere already on here, I just cannot find it. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

I am using jQuery to create a Tab system inside a webpage. When the response of a query is finished it will load the results in a new tab, and set the other tabs to have the CSS `style="display: none;"`. Most of this is handled by jQueryUI.

I have a function I am trying to run that will throw an error if the content of those tabs are not visible. I am looking for something like `document.ready()` for the tab element. This isn't exactly it because the element is still loaded into the DOM so `$('#tab-content').ready()` runs even though the item is hidden. Is there someway to set up a promise or an event listener with a callback that runs when an elements hidden property changes?

I have read the following docs about $.when and $.this, however I am not sure I fully understand promises and deffer to properly implement this.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to see when an element has been changed.

In my example below, I'm creating a paragraph that is initially hidden. An observer is setup to this element that, when changed, will log `"change!"`. At the bottom, I'm making the element visible which runs the mutation.

To check if the element has been made visible, you can first check within the `mutations forEach` loop that `mutation.type` is equal to `"attributes"`. If it is, you can then check if the element is visible.

```js
var testElement = document.getElementById('test-element');
 
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log("change!"); // run some change when the style is mutated
    });    
});
 
observer.observe(testElement, {
    attributes: true
});

testElement.style.display = "block"; // simulate a change
```

```html
<p style="display: none;" id="test-element">Testing</p>
```

Once you're finished observing, you should apparently then call `observer.disconnect()` which will no longer look for changes.